# Change EJS Template Directory

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, ejs

I'm using EJS with Rails 4. Right now my code looks like:

```
// in javascripts/helpers.js
function render(template_path, data) {
   return JST['templates/' + template_path](data);
}
```

which allows me to put my ejs templates in javascripts/templates and then render them with:

```
//This will render javascripts/templates/about/photos
render("about/photos",{ iLength: iLength })
```

But now I need to change the directory to be inside my views directory. My .ejs files are now in **views/stores/**

Is this possible? Thanks for and any all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

From the [Rails Asset Pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization), you can add folders to the asset pipeline by appending paths to `config.assets.paths`. So if the path you wanted to add was `app/views/stores`, you should modify `config/application.rb` like so:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "views", "stores")
```

Next, you have to let your `application.js` file know to load your javascript templates. Assuming your `application.js` file is in the `app/assets/javascripts` folder, one way to do that would be to add the following:

```
//= require_tree ../../views/stores
```

i.e. the path to your new directory.

Another way to achieve that without using relative paths is to add a file called `javascript-templates.js` (or some other suitable name) to the root of your stores folder like so:

```
.
└── views
    └── stores
        ├── foo
        │   ├── bar.jst.ejs
        │   └── baz.jst.ejs
        └── javascript-templates.js
```

and in `javascript-templates.js` add the following line:

```
//= require_tree .
```

then in `application.js` add the following

```
//= require javascript-templates
```

where javascript-templates is whatever you decided to name the above mentioned file.

After restarting your rails server, the JST object should now contain the templates found in your `app/views/stores` folder. In the above example, you could access the template found in `views/stores/foo/bar.jst.ejs` with:

```
JST['foo/bar']()
```

I would probably just stick with the app/assets folder though.